# Aligning Input field to the left

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I'm styling a Form at the moment and struggle with a pretty basic problem.
I'm working on an Ionic 3 App and want to have a ngClass for the Input to be shorter than normal.
if I just set the width of the input to X% it looks like this:
[image: Screenshot]

My CSS looks like this:

```
.formInput{
    width:100%;
    ::placeholder{
        padding-left: 1% !important;
    }
    padding-left: 1% !important;
    margin-top: 1%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid rgb(145, 145, 145);
    border-radius: 10px ;
    color: #78C800;
}
```

EDIT:

HTML:

```
<ion-item class="formItem" *ngIf="obj.show">
    <ion-label stacked>{{obj.label}}</ion-label>
  <ion-input class="formInput shorten" *ngIf="pageIsReady" type="{{obj.type}}" [placeholder]="obj.></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

I've tried `float: left` and `text-align: left` on both the Input and the ion-item. Nothing's working though.

Comment: add this part to css `float:left` and you haven't added the bottom stylings to anywhere according to the snippet. please let me know if this works, so i can add as an answer :)

Comment: is the input an ion-item? can you show the html part of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ion-input` uses flexbox to align the content:

Default css from inspect element:

```css
position: relative;
display: block;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-webkit-flex: 1;
-ms-flex: 1;
flex: 1;
width: 100%;
```

Use `align-self:flex-start` to left align in your class

```css
.formInput{
      width:50%;//or X% 
      ::placeholder{
          padding-left: 1% !important;
      }
      padding-left: 1% !important;
      margin-top: 1%;
      background-color: white;
       border: 1px solid rgb(145, 145, 145);
       border-radius: 10px ;
      color: #78C800;
      align-self: flex-start;//here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add float:left; or text-align:left; in your css for .formInput

EDIT:

I got it now: you should separately put .formInput::placeholder {} then it will work.

```
.formInput{
width:100%;
float:left;
padding-left: 1% !important;
margin-top: 1%;
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid rgb(145, 145, 145);
border-radius: 10px ;
color: #78C800;
}
.formInput::placeholder{
  padding-left: 1% !important;
}
```

Comment: are the other properties coming?

Comment: i changed it to be the last property. Still not working.

Comment: Now try the same thing: Give it a one last try, if it doesn't work there must be some other issue...

Comment: even if i delte the ::placeholder alltogether, its still not working. I think i broke CSS :|

Comment: Just check other parts of your css

Comment: Thank you! i'm just working around it with margin until i find a solution

Comment: it is nested because OP is using SCSS. putting it outside does nothing

Answer (score 0):

Add float:left to the input field.

```
.formInput{
width:100%;
float:left;
::placeholder{
  padding-left: 1% !important;
}
padding-left: 1% !important;
margin-top: 1%;
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid rgb(145, 145, 145);
border-radius: 10px ;
color: #78C800;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it's not working for me. Its still aligning in the center

Comment: Did you try inline styling

Comment: i did and it's not working. The whole thing is inside a formArray, maybe that's where the problem is? I've inspected it in the browser and there is nothing that should keep it from aligning to the left

Answer (score -1):

Change your .formItem width instead.

For example:

```
.formItem {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}

.formInput {
    width: 100%;
    ...
}
```